# How to guarantee ordering of instruction in C

Tags: c, instructions, instruction-reordering

My multithreaded code is as follows:

thread A

```
while(true) {
  foo();
  sleep();
}
```

thread B

```
...
bar_off();
bar_on();
...
```

foo() isn't safe to be executed when bar_off is called and until bar_on has completed.

I could rewrite my code as follows:

int volatile foo_is_safe=0;

thread A

```
while(true) {
  if (foo_is_safe) {
    foo();
  }
  sleep();
}
```

thread B

```
...
foo_is_safe=0;
bar_off();
bar_on();
foo_is_safe=1;
...
```

But I believe this won't work since the compiler is not required to preserve the ordering between setting foo_is_safe and calling the bar_* functions.  I am not even sure the compiler will not simply ignore setting foo_is_safe to 0.

Am I correct?  What's the proper way to make my code safe, i.e. enforce foo_is_safe is set before bar_off() and after bar_on()?

Comment: You can use a Mutex.

Comment: Or you can use `atomic_bool`. But you still have a problem if thread A sees that `foo_is_Safe` is true, so it calls `foo()`. Before `foo()` returns, thread B calls `bar_off()`. You now have `foo()` running while `bar` is off, which is what you were trying to prevent.

Comment: I don't see how atomics would solve my problems. Yes, I am currently using a mutex surrounding the calls to bar_* and around my call to foo. But I was wondering/hoping if there was a way to simply enforce that my accesses to foo_is_safe are not permuted with the function callls around them.

Comment: Unlike volatiles, atomics do provide ordering guarantees. But since you're already wrapping the whole thing inside a mutex, the mutex itself is sufficient to avoid the data races, because `mtx_unlock` is *synchronized-with* and therefore *happens-before* `mtx_lock`. This is, indeed, the purpose of mutexes.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the clarifications: I didn't know atomics guaranteed ordering Q1. Since atomics would work, wouldn't using an atomic be a better, lower overhead implementation than a mutex? Q2. How do I know what other C operations guarantee ordering?

Comment: Q1: The atomic is lower overhead, but it also means that a `bar_off()` can begin while a `foo()` is active. It's not clear whether that's something you want to allow. Q2: The C standard specifies which operations guarantee ordering. Basically, atomics, mutexes, once_flag, thread creation, and thread join.